# Manipulação de registros (regedit)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Tenho um aplicativo desenvolvido em windows forms que manipula alguns registros no seguinte caminho: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\MINHAEMPRESA\etc...". Este aplicativo era executado como administrador e nunca tive problema com a manipulação desses registros, por alguns motivos empresariais, meu aplicativo não poderá mais ser executado como adm e com isso não consigo mais manipular esses registros.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum lugar nos registros que a gravação e leitura possam ser realizados através de um app sem direitos de adm, e que esse local seja disponível a todos os usuários.

Obs: Não posso optar por outra solução que não seja os registros, pois os valores manipulados são lidos por um aplicativo de terceiro o qual não possuo o código fonte. O sistema operacional em que o aplicativo é instalado é o windows 10.

Comment: Sem privilégios de administrador só será possível escrever em **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`**

Comment: @LINQ obrigado pela resposta, saberia me informar se escrevendo neste local fica acessível para outros usuários?

Comment: Não, fica apenas para o usuário corrente.

Comment: Você altera com frêquencia esses valores ou apenas na instalação do seu aplicativo?

Comment: Com frequência @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 0):

---

> - **1)** Uma chave que é passível de **ler/escrever**, é a chave usada para **variáveis globais**:
> - Use  **[`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)**

---

---

> - **2)** Possivelmente não é muito indicada, mas passível de **ler/escrever também**
> - Use **[`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root)**

---

Uma chave no registro do Windows para escrever sem usar credencial de administrador, acessível por qualquer usuário, e em substituição a <kbd>**`HKLM\SOFTWARE\MINHAEMPRESA\...`**</kbd>.

---

Use uma chave destinada para mesclar valores entre  <kbd>**`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classe | & | HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classe`**</kbd>

---

<kbd>**`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`**</kbd> <= mescla =>  <kbd>**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`**</kbd>

---

Os valores adicionados <kbd>**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`**</kbd> vai gravar <kbd>**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`**</kbd>

---

**Obs.:**

---

> - Quando você escrever algum valor na chave:....................................<kbd>**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`**</kbd>
> - E o valor já existir na chave:..................................<kbd>**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`**</kbd>
> - Sistema vai salvar esse valor em:.........................<kbd>**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`**</kbd>
> - Em vez de salvar/adicionar/substituir em:...........<kbd>**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`**</kbd>
>
>   ---

Fica a sugestão de ler esse mais sobre o uso da chave <kbd>**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`**</kbd> nessa questão no [SO/en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984433/hkey-local-machine-software-classes-vs-hkey-classes-root) e [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root)!

---